# How to get items separately (one by one) from item view modal

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How i can get items as string in item view modal. 
I have tried the following but they are not giving me correct output.

```
 if (Opf.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                StreamWriter swa = new StreamWriter(Opf.FileName);
                using (swa)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < PlayList.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var ix = PlayList.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString();
                        swa.WriteLine(ix);
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("List Saved.");
            }
```

It gives me

Wss.ItemViewModal

Wss.ItemViewModal

Wss.ItemViewModal

Wss.ItemViewModal

How i can get item from my listbox. My listbox xaml code

```
  <ListBox Name="PlayList" Margin="0,50,0,30" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" MouseDoubleClick="PlayList_MouseDoubleClick">
            <!--Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="PlayList_SelectionChanged"-->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Sname}"    FontSize="20"  Foreground="White" x:Name="SongNameList" Margin="0"           HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Width="193"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Duration}" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Orange" x:Name="DurationList" Margin="189,0,0,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Width="62"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Isvid}"    FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="DeepPink" x:Name="VideoC"       Margin="0,0,300,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Width="55"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Format }"  FontSize="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="Orange" x:Name="Format"       Margin="0,0,220,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Width="50"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding YTL}"      FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" x:Name="YT"           Margin="0,0,100,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Width="148"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding SNN}"      FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="SkyBlue" x:Name="SN"           Margin="0"    HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding VPath }"   FontSize="20" Foreground="Green" x:Name="Path"  Margin="256,0,332,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Anything more you want to ask just comment.

Thank you very much .

Comment: Please include the source code for `Wss.ItemViewModal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if not overriden in class, `ToString()` returns class name with namespace which heppen to be `Wss.ItemViewModal`. Overriding `ToString()` for export purposes is hardly optimal solution - export formats can vary for a single class! It makes more sense to implement `IFormattable` in ItemViewModal and specify format.

Alternatively: don't use ToString and list all properties which should be exported:

```
if (Opf.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (StreamWriter swa = new StreamWriter(Opf.FileName))
    {
        foreach(ItemViewModal vm in PlayList.Items)
        {
            var ix = vm.Sname + " " + vm.Duration;
            swa.WriteLine(ix);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("List Saved.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the method *ToString()* of your *ItemViewModel* class.

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
   ...
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return $"ItemViewModel: {Sname} {Duration} {Isvid} {Format } {YTL} {SNN} {VPath}";
   }
   ...
}
```